# How to keep the reference of the singleton class object in the companion object, Kotlin

Tags: android, libgdx, kotlin, static-variables, kotlin-companion

The code that I want to convert is the following;

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

   public static AndroidLauncher androidLauncher;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       androidLauncher = this;
   }
}
```

What android studio generated code is this;

```
class AndroidLauncher : AndroidApplication() {
   protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       androidLauncher = this
   }

   companion object {

       var androidLauncher: AndroidLauncher
   }
}
```

This code gives me error, which is;

> Property must be initialized or be abstract

I'm developing a game with libgdx, so I'll use this approach to use the Game object from anywhere I want. It's a singleton class so it won't leak any memory.

Comment: `AndroidLauncher` is an `Activity`

Comment: It does not matter. However, keeping a static variable of an activity would leak memory which I'm not planning on.

Comment: @tynn `AndroidLauncher` is an `Application`, not an `Activity`...

Comment: @m0skit0 it's actually both in different domains https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lateinit` to indicate that the field will be initialized later.

```
   companion object {
       lateinit var androidLauncher: AndroidLauncher
   }
```